# Failed to install 'cordova-plugin-app-version':TypeError: Uh oh! Object #<Object> has no method 'parse'

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins

I upgraded cordova and platform, and created new project while installing app-version plugin giving `"object has no method parse"`.

[image]

PFA

Comment: I have exactly the same issue, did you figure out how to resolve it yet?

Comment: No still searching....  If you figured it out let me know @Emmy

Comment: Its worked, just upgraded the node.js its worked fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because of outdated npm plugins are not installing

Answer (score 0):

try cordova-plugin-appinfo.  It is very simple and easy to use.